# How to read specific range from a csv file and write to another csv file in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

This is the code I have been using to read all the records from CSV file. I am quite new to the java.

```
FileReader openFile = new FileReader("/Users/ABC/Desktop/Test/myFirstFile.csv"); 

    BufferedReader readMyDataObj = new BufferedReader(openFile)
    FileWriter writer2 = new FileWriter("/Users/ABC/Desktop/Test/mySecondFile.csv");
    BufferedWriter bf2 = new BufferedWriter(writer2);
    String data2;
    while ((data2=readMyDataObj.readLine())!=null) {    
    bf2.write(data2);
    bf2.newLine();       
     }
    bf2.close();                   
    writer2.close();
    openFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a very good example for your requirement - read and also filter examples are present
https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write data to a JSON file your best bet is to use a standard Java library like [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired results by using some variables and a counter around the main while loop. Also, it might make sense to take into account whether or not the input csv file has a header row.

Main.java

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader inFile = new FileReader("a.csv");
        BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(inFile);

        FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("b.csv");
        BufferedWriter outWriter = new BufferedWriter(outFile);

        // Range to read/write
        int low = 5;
        int high = 10;

        int count = 1;
        String line = inReader.readLine();
        while (line != null && count < high) {
            if (count >= low) {
                outWriter.write(line);
                outWriter.newLine();
            }

            line = inReader.readLine();
            count++;
        }

        inReader.close();
        inFile.close();
        outWriter.close();
        outFile.close();
    }
```

a.csv

```
ID,First Name,Last Name,City,State,Age,Height
iW00K,Jane,Bosco,Lake Dandreland,ME,61,170.57
BzxTl,Steve,Smith,Uniqueside,PA,35,152.93
vobj8,Tony,Auer,Tressiestad,MS,63,160.86
X78RS,Steve,Cole,Port Zellachester,OH,72,159.84
0YpWG,John,Lu,East Vernaview,OH,18,200
4JaoZ,Peter,Simonis,Wernerchester,HI,25,161.64
hP48C,Tom,Lu,Uniqueside,ME,45,161.64
WDQpb,John,Casper,East Felicityshire,OH,42,170.57
wyPwB,Jane,Johns,Maggiehaven,CA,16,180.42
VCtYR,Peter,Jast,Schadenberg,ME,41,161.64
1VYOs,John,Daniel,Port Zellachester,HI,34,200
V7pg9,Tom,Mayert,Schadenberg,OH,71,152.93
SmE9w,Jane,Lu,Stephanchester,HI,25,176.95
ALyok,Tom,Smith,Ryanchester,PA,70,176.95
fgE5v,Peter,Bailey,Bednarstad,PA,67,170.24
eBIIM,Peter,Haley,East Vernaview,MS,65,161.64
5sv4L,Peter,Prosacco,Uniqueside,PA,50,178.25
a48IS,Peter,Marvin,Kossview,OH,63,200
9mLcZ,John,VonRueden,East Vernaview,PA,20,174.24
```

b.csv

```
X78RS,Steve,Cole,Port Zellachester,OH,72,159.84
0YpWG,John,Lu,East Vernaview,OH,18,200
4JaoZ,Peter,Simonis,Wernerchester,HI,25,161.64
hP48C,Tom,Lu,Uniqueside,ME,45,161.64
WDQpb,John,Casper,East Felicityshire,OH,41,170.57
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!